# Filter useful data from an input file

Tags: php

I have a fairly large and very messy data file from which I wish to filter useful data. Its structure looks something like this:

```
!bla bla
more bla
some useless data
something interesting
 something interesting
 something interesting
some useless data
something interesting
 something interesting
some useless data
bla bla
```

My plan was to read the file with `file_get_contents()`, then use `str_replace()` to replace some data and use it as markers. Next, I tried to remove useless data from the beginning of the file to `marker1`, then from `marker2` to `marker3`, then from `marker4` to the end of the file, so that I would only get the useful data in the output (at this point I'm not yet sure if I will or will not need the markers in the data). I tried using `strstr()` but could not make it work.

```
    !bla bla
    more bla
    some useless data
    ==marker1==
    something interesting
     something interesting
     something interesting
    ==marker2==
    some useless data
    ==marker3==
    something interesting
     something interesting
    ==marker4==
    some useless data
    bla bla
```

I will be using `explode()` to transfer the resulting useful data to my database.

EDIT:
Well i got this solved like this.

```
preg_match('/(==marker1==)(.*?)(==marker2==)/s', $input, $marker1to2);
$marker1to2 = trim($marker1to2[2]); 
$marker1to2 = preg_replace('/something /', '==marker1== something ', $marker1to2, 1); 
echo $marker1to2;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need regular expressions:

```
$data = "!bla bla
more bla
some useless data
==marker1==
something interesting
 something interesting
 something interesting
==marker2==
some useless data
==marker3==
something interesting
 something interesting
==marker4==
some useless data
bla bla";

preg_match("/(==marker1==)(.*)(==marker2==)/s", $data, $marker1to2);
$marker1to2 = trim($marker1to2[2]);

preg_match("/(==marker3==)(.*)(==marker4==)/s", $data, $marker3to4);
$marker3to4 = trim($marker3to4[2]);

echo "Marker 1 to 2:\n$marker1to2\n\n";
echo "Marker 3 to 4:\n$marker3to4\n\n";
```

Output:

```
Marker 1 to 2:
something interesting
something interesting
something interesting

Marker 3 to 4:
something interesting
something interesting
```

Comment: It works on your example, but when i try to apply the same principle to my data, nothing happens. Is there another simple approach to this? Maybe something with strstr()? 
I tried looking up something that would work like strstr($data, $from_marker1, $to_marker2) but no such luck. :)

Comment: Can you post some real data please? I will test my regex again with the real data.

Comment: The data is from a firewall config file, i cant really put it up online.

Comment: Is your marker really called `==marker1==`? Please add `var_dump($marker1to2)` before `$marker1to2 = ...` to see if there is some output.

Comment: This is what var_dump() returns: 
seems correct, me thinks :|, but the output still comes with the text that i want to remove. 

array (size=4)
  0 => string 'content of marker1 
text between markers
content of marker2' (length=105)
  1 => string 'content of marker1' (length=23)
  2 => string ' 
text between markers
' (length=35)
  3 => string 'content of marker2' (length=47)

Comment: So is `2 => string ' text between markers '` the content you want to get? How does your "real" marker look? If the real marker contains any special character used in regular expressions, you have to encode it first.

Comment: I think i got this now. I used what you suggested like this:

// selected the text from the first occurrence of marker1 to the first occurrence of marker2.

preg_match('/(==marker1==)(.*?)(==marker2==)/s', $input, $marker1to2);

$marker1to2 = trim($marker1to2[2]);


// and then added back the marker1, because i will need it later
// note: there is a bunch of marker1 and marker2 instances and the "?" is to find just the first occurrence of marker2

$marker1to2 = preg_replace('/something /', '==marker1==something ', $marker1to2, 1);


Thanks for the help.